# how to check next item in linq 2 sql query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have such this table:

```
position             title
---------------------------
1                     "t1"
2                     "t1"
3                     "t2"
4                     "t1"
5                     "t2"
```

I want to filter "t1" title but for positions that current position and next position have 1 difference. According this if **I want first "t1" the result should be [1,2].**

How I can write this query using linq 2 sql?

Comment: First, figure out how you would do it in TSQL.... not sure that is a trivial query.

Comment: Sorry dear Marc but I don't know TSQL query for it

Comment: So you want that qiery returns 2 lines (if succeed), or the collection of lines "pairs"?

Comment: @Tigran: I want just return 2 rows if it succeed

Comment: @Nima: Why would you get 2 rows? Only row 1 has another "t1" directly after it - row 2 shouldn't be returned, because row 3 has "t2". If you really want row 3 returned, you need to clarify your criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a self-join:

```
var query = from item1 in db.Items.Where(x => x.title == "t1")
            from item2 in db.Items.Where(x => x.title == "t1")
            where item1.position + 1 == item2.position
            select item1; // Adjust however you want, e.g. new { item1, item2 }
```

Now I don't know whether that will actually work in SQL... but logically it's what you want.

Comment: this is TSQL of your code :exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[Position], [t0].[Title]
FROM [dbo].[Headers] AS [t0], [dbo].[Headers] AS [t1]
WHERE (([t0].[Position] + @p0) = [t1].[Position]) AND ([t0].[Title] = @p1) AND ([t1].[Title] = @p2)',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=1,@p1=N't1',@p2=N't1'

Comment: @Nima: Only the first row has an directly item after it with the position directly after it.

Comment: yes but I want "t1" for rows that are seriate.please see bold text in my Question

Comment: @Nima: You've said which results you want, but not why. You could change the select to return both item1 and item2, so each result contains the "current" row and its matching "next" one. That would be simpler than having another condition.